# How to know when a pop-down menu needs to be closed

Tags: javascript, html

I'm experimenting with pop-down menus (inside floating DIVs). Making them appear with `onmouseover` attributes is no problem, but I'm not sure how I can make the menu close properly.

I'm dealing with an image that has links mapped over it with `<map>`. I want people to see a menu when hovering over a link.

I figured the best way to know when to close the menu is wait until the mouse is no longer hovering over the HTML element that called the menu or the menu itself, then wait one second, and then close the menu.

Is my idea something that can be implemented, perhaps with some jQuery? Or is there a better and more efficient alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will throw my recommendation behind the jQuery [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) plugin. Should be up and running quickly, very configurable, and no need to roll your own code.

Comment: Looks promising, but for it to work I cannot use another HTML element (I use a DIV), right?

Comment: No, you should be able to use whatever you want.

Comment: But then how does it know when to call the "close menu" code if the actual menu is not part of the element that called the "open menu" code?

Comment: In your out function, you can check for presence over your menu. If the cursor is there, ignore it; otherwise, close your menu. Bind a similar hoverIntent "out" event to your menu: if you leave the menu, close it.

Comment: That's the thing... how do I know the mouse is hovering over the menu?

Answer (score 0):

with jquery:

```
$("your-menu-button-selector, your-menu-selector").bind("mouseleave", function(e){
  clearTimeout($(this).data("mouseleaveTimeout"));
  $(this).data("mouseleaveTimeout", setTimeout(function(){
     //your code
     //closeMenu();
  }, 1000)); //one second
});
```

you also want to clear the timeout when opening the menu!

```
$("your-menu-button-selector, your-menu-selector").bind("mouseenter", function(e){
  clearTimeout($(this).data("mouseleaveTimeout"));
  //your code
  //openMenu()
});
```

I understand it now, you can have the same thing apply also to the link and the menu box so that when hovering the options, it does not disappear.

Comment: I have an issue with that. If I hover my mouse over the menu for too long (i.e. over 1 second) without clicking anything, it closes.

Comment: @Pieter Then you remove the one second set timeout

Comment: @Pieter, you mean that is what you want, to have it also closed when hovering more than, say, 10 seconds? I am going to edit my answer for that.

Comment: I want the menu to open when the user hovers over a certain element (let's say a#link1) and stay open as long as the mouse doesn't leave a#link1 or the menu for more than 2 seconds.

Comment: Ok, now I get it, of course.  You just bind the same event to it.  I have edited my answer, you just change the jQuery selector.

Answer (score 0):

I did some additional digging myself. http://javascript-array.com/scripts/jquery_simple_drop_down_menu/

I need to somehow combine this with a `<map>` that makes parts of an image invoke a drop-down menu. Do you think this can get the job done?